# not sure what is wrong in this implementation

Tags: ocaml

```
type 'a tree = Leaf of 'a
               |Fork of 'a tree * 'a tree
```

can someone show the right way to do this?

Comment: What is the error it gives you?

Comment: the constructer fork expects 2 arguments but is applied here to 3 arguments

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is telling you the following. You declared `Fork` like this:

```
| Fork of 'a tree * 'a tree
```

(Fixing a typo in your code btw.)

This indeed has two parameters, each of type `'a tree`.

If you look at any of your `Fork` constructors you'll see that you're giving them three values. Here's one from the middle of your expression:

```
Fork(4, Leaf, Leaf)
```

You either need to change your definition of `Fork` or you need to supply only two values when using the `Fork` constructor.

If you want values in your internal nodes you should modify your definition of `Fork` to include a value (of type `'a` presumably). If the values are all supposed to be at the leaves, you need to change  your expression.

**Update**

Here is a working definition of a tree using your current definitions:

```
# let (t: int tree) = Fork (Leaf 1, Leaf 2);;
val t : int tree = Fork (Leaf 1, Leaf 2)
```

I should also point out that you're using `Leaf` with zero parameters, but you have declared it to take one parameter (as in my example here).

Comment: You used the wrong two parameters. You have declared two parameters of type `'a tree`. This experiment is using one of type `int` and one of type `'a tree`.